# How to show toolbar on ADOBE XD

Tags: adobe, adobe-xd

I'm trying to use **ADOBE XD** following some guides, but I can't find how to enable the **toolbar** (File, Edit, Object, ecc.) that you can see in this pic:

[image]

I'm working on **windows 10** and I have just the **hamburger menu**, and inside it I can't find any way to enabled the toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an answer for your question in Adobe forum:
"This is a UWP design paradigm that we are following. You will be able to find everything file-related in the hamburger menu, and everything object-related either in a context menu or in the property inspector"

Reference:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2397212